# Calling cors(req,res,() => {}) without a req/res objects via a Firebase Functions trigger

Tags: node.js, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use cors(req,res,() => {... - it works well using the Firebase Functions HTTP function, but I want to call cors within a Firebase Functions trigger, which doesn't provide a req,res variables obviously.

Cors seem to demand these parameters. How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not writing an HTTP type function, there is no request and response, because there is no client directly invoking the function over an HTTP connection.  Cors is not at all helpful in those cases.